# How to make collapsed content to be expanded on load

Tags: jquery, css

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
$(".collapse").collapse({

      open: function() {

        this.slideDown(300);

        el = this.parent().find("h3 a")[0];

        $(el).text("-").prop('title', 'Collapse');


      },

      close: function() {

        this.slideUp(300);

        el = this.parent().find("h3 a")[0];
        $(el).text("+").prop('title', 'Expand');


      },
      accordion: true,
      persist: false
    });
```

I have this code and on loading the page the content is collapsed, so i click on '+' and it gets expanded. I want it to be expanded on load ( respectfully, the icon will be '-' and the content will be expanded, and after clicking it, it will change into '+' and the content would be collapsed.

Comment: What is the plugins name for the collapse functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following class to your object:

```
class="open"
```

It will be open by default.